# How to recursively generate and save csv files to a specific directory?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am working on a code that gets as input a zip file that contains excel files, extract them in a folder, convert them in dataframes and load all these dataframes files in a list. I would like to create a new folder, convert those dataframes in csv files and save them in the above-mentioned folder. The goal is to be able to download as a zip file a folder of csv files.

The main problem for me is to make sure that every csv file has the name of the excel file it was originated from.

I'm adding my code, in the first block there's the first part of the code, while in the second one there's the part of the code in which i have a problem.

running this last part of the code i get this error:
"XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xef\xbb\xbf;data'"

---

```
%%capture
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os.path

!pip install xlrd==1.2.0

from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

%%capture
zipname = list(uploaded.keys())[0]
destination_path = 'files'
infolder = os.path.join('/content/', destination_path)

!unzip -o $zipname -d $destination_path

# Load an excel file, return events dataframe + file header dataframe
def load_xlsx(fullpath):
   return events, meta

tasks = [os.path.join(dp, fname) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(infolder) for fname in filenames if fname.lower().endswith('.xls')]

dfs = []
metas = []

for fname in tasks:
  df, meta = load_xlsx(fname)
  dfs.append(df)
  metas.append(meta)
```

---

```
newpath = 'csv2021'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)
filepath = os.path.join('/content/files/', newpath)

for fname in tasks:
   filename = load_xlsx(fname)
   my_csv = filename.to_csv(os.path.join(filepath, filename), encoding="utf-8-sig" , sep = ';')
```

Comment: your error seems like it has more to do with your data (files) than it does with your code

Comment: You definitely need to know what kind of data you are dealing with, and if nobody knows what kind of data they are, that becomes really impossible to work on. You can add samples of data to your question, and sample of expected output.